# Next js: next auth provider + redux provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-auth

In my Next js project, I have used Next auth, which `import {Provider} from 'next-auth/client'`, and wrap the `<Component />` in _app.js.

However, at the same time, I want to add redux in the project. And it will `import {Provider} from 'react-redux'`, and need to wrap the `<Component />` in _app.js also.

So in this situation, they are using the same `Provider`, I have tried import destructing, but it got me a synatx error `Syntax error: ES2015 named imports do not destructure. Use another statement for destructuring after the import.`. So how can I do?

```
import { Provider } from "next-auth/client";  
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
        <Provider
          options={{     
            clientMaxAge: 0,
            keepAlive: 0,
          }}
          session={pageProps.session}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rename destructured imports. So your code may look something like this:

```js
import { Provider } from "next-auth/client";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider {/* whatever props go here */}>
        <Provider
          options={{     
            clientMaxAge: 0,
            keepAlive: 0,
          }}
          session={pageProps.session}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: does the order in which component is wrapped matter? shouldn't the session provider be on top of the redux provider?